# How to render stars in 3d.js without using THREE.Geometry()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, 3d

I was trying to create a space scene and tried to render stars. First, I tried using sphere geometry as a star but creating so many stars using *sphere geometry will put a lot of rendering work and will take time*. So, when I searched for alternatives I found **THREE.Geometry()** but now it is **discontinued** and is not available with the package I am using. So, is there any other alternative to get the job done? Maybe **BufferGeometry()** but I don't know how to use it to create stars and also I found many of the tutorials explaining how to make shapes using it and not point objects throughout the space.

Comment: Take a look at InstancedMesh.

Comment: Use `THREE.Points()` instead. The latest example I made with stars of points is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sea-ed1ov (`Stars.js` module in `js` folder)